# PSQL account owner of a schema but can not create tables

Tags: postgresql, psql

Within a PSQL database I have an schema named:

```
tmp_atlas_mdcr2003_2021
```

and the owner of this schema is the account atlasuser. This user is always used to "communicate and run queries" against the tmp_atlas_mdcr2003_2021 schema.

However, it was received the next error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [create table tmp_atlas_mdcr2003_2021.temp_cohort_ylv7yw28

(

  COHORT_DEFINITION_ID int NOT NULL,

  SUBJECT_ID bigint NOT NULL,

  cohort_start_date date NOT NULL,

  cohort_end_date date NOT NULL

)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for schema tmp_atlas_mdcr2003_2021
```

How the owner of a psql schema can not create a table within his own schema? atlasuser is not the owner of the database where this schema has been created.

How can this error be corrected?

Comment: Do you have the log of how `atlasuser` was created, e.g. [CREATE USER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-createuser.html) and what privileges were granted to that user, e.g. [GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)? (those would be helpful, but remove any credential info, passwords, etc. before posting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user `atlasuser` is indeed the owner of schema `tmp_atlas_mdcr2003_2021`, then the only explanation is that the user is missing the `CREATE` privilege on the schema. You can grant that with

```
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA tmp_atlas_mdcr2003_2021 TO atlasuser;
```

If that doesn't do the trick, one of your assumptions must be incorrect. Verify the ownership and permissions with

```
SELECT nspowner::regrole AS owner,
       coalesce(nspacl::text, 'NULL') AS permissions
FROM pg_namespace
WHERE nspname = 'tmp_atlas_mdcr2003_2021';
```